# Trying to make a shopping cart in php, form isnt defining indexes correctly

Tags: php, html, shopping-cart

Just that, here's some of he code i use

```
<?php
    include('lib_carrito.php');
    session_start();
?>
<form action="mete_producto.php" method="POST">
            <input type="hidden" name="producto" value="<?php echo $nombre ?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="precio" value="<?php echo $precio ?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="producto" value="<?php echo $Id ?>">
            <?php


                if ($stock == 0 || !(isset($_SESSION['usuario'])) || $_SESSION['autoridad'] == 1) {
                    echo "<input type='submit' class='disabled' value='Añadir al carrito'>";
                }
                else{
                    echo "<input type='submit' class='añadir' value='Añadir al carrito'>";
                }
                ?>
                <select name="cantidad" style="height:35px; font-size: 25px">
                <?php
                    for ($i=1; $i <= $stock; $i++) { 
                        echo "<option value='".$i."'>".$i."</option>";
                    }
                ?>
                </select>
        </form>
```

That's on the page with the item the customer would buy,
then this is mete_producto.php

```
<?php
include("lib_carrito.php");
require('config.php');
session_start();
$_SESSION['ocarrito']->introduce_producto($_REQUEST["Id"], $_REQUEST["Nombre"], $_REQUEST["Precio"], $_REQUEST['Cantidad']);
//header("Location:index.php");
```

?>
I have the header as a comment so it would show me the errors,
for all of them is the same error 'Undefined index: Id'

Answer (score 1):

You haven't defined either `Id` or `Nombre` as `name` attributes to be sent with your form. You have, however, assigned two `producto` names which have corresponding PHP variables. I assume this is how you are intending to use these variables.

Instead of:

```
<input type="hidden" name="producto" value="<?php echo $nombre ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="precio" value="<?php echo $precio ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="producto" value="<?php echo $Id ?>">
```

You're looking for:

```
<input type="hidden" name="nombre" value="<?php echo $nombre ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="precio" value="<?php echo $precio ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="Id" value="<?php echo $Id ?>">
```